# Is it possible to check if a flag is defined without having a predefined lookup table and given only the flag name as a string?

Tags: c

I am writing a program that will call a function from an external library, given a list of bitfield flags provided by the end user of my program. I was initially planning on maintaining a lookup table of all the possible flags, but the list of flags varies by platform and I don't have complete documentation for the library. I had planned to use the c preprocessor to include only the defined flags for the current platform in the table, but this is turning out to be hard to maintain because I have to rely on users reporting missing flags for platforms to which I don't have access.

I then thought I could allow the users to pass in the flag names as strings. But I can't find a way to test if a macro is defined, given only the string name of the macro. So if a user wanted to set the flag FLAG_ABC, they'd pass in "FLAG_ABC" as an argument and I'd have to do some magic to check if &FLAG_ABC != NULL. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Not a code example, but please let me know what part of the post I need to clarify.

Comment: So am I right in saying that you want to check at run-time if something is #define-d?

Comment: Yes, I guess that what it boils down to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `#define`'s are lost after preprocessing. If you want to have the information of preprocessor-symbols available at run-time you have to have the names (and values of course) of these macros as strings in your executable OR as a separate file which you then fread at run-time. I could imagine it would be anoying to have two lists of flags, one with the #define-symbols and one with the strings and then manually caring that if you update the one you also update the other without error.

I would go with the separate file you load at run-time but instead of having the updating-trouble just have that file be a header-file you also `#include`. Specifically what i suggest is: move all your flag-definition `#define's` into a separate header-file, include it in your sources so you can use it as you are used to, create a mini-parser reading in the file at run-time, i.e. parsing each line `#define asdf 0xF1A6` into a string and an int. If this works in practice and you then want to prevent the user from accidentally changing that header-file you could either hash it or binary-encode it.

The alternative with which you can have the `#define`-symbols as strings actually in your binary would be to generate a `.rc`-file from that header file (or both the header-file and the `.rc` from a `.csv`-file) and then using the resource-compiler to inline it in your binary's `.rsrc`-section, you have to write the helper-program (which transforms the file) though and integrate a call to that transformer-program into your make-script or build-system to always have the `.rc` up-to-date.